# "rem" comment in .bat file causes error "25 was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, comments

Isn't this weird?  Do .bat rem commands have some kind of escape code?

file.bat:

```
rem https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25
```

Running it:

```
C:\Users\admin>file.bat
25 was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\admin>https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25
```

I don't see any errorlevel.

Comment: not quite weird. rem  has parameters, well one  which is `/?`

Comment: @Gerhard yes, I just narrowed it down.  I had a web address as a comment and it really threw me off.

Comment: ah, yes, I see the edit. So I will link you to something to show you how cmd interprets a script.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) which should help you understand, I could have explained, but why should I if it was already done :)

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks.  I put the original web link back in, to show how confusing it can be.

Comment: Yes, so one way to eliminate it, seeing as it is a `rem`ark is to double quote it. `rem "https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25"`

Answer (score 5):

The `rem` command supports one argument, namely `/?`, and it is greedy for it. Your URL contains that string.

The `=` is a standard token separator (just like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`), and so the remainder seems to be interpreted as another (invalid) command.

Putting the remark text in between quotation marks helps here since `/?` is no longer detected:

```cmd
rem "https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25"
```

When you write this:

```cmd
rem/ https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25
```

the `/?` portion is no longer detected too. However, special characters like `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `(` and `)` are then recognised.

---

Another alternative is to use a `::`-style comment, which is actually an invalid label (labels begin with a `:`, see `goto /?` and `call /?`):

```cmd
:: https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=25
```

Special characters are not a problem here, but this must not be used within a parenthesised block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's weird.  Rem is like a regular command that answers to /? for help, even if the /? is buried somewhere in another string.  I'm told that putting the address in doublequotes fixes it.

```
C:\Users\admin>rem /?
Records comments (remarks) in a batch file or CONFIG.SYS.

REM [comment]
```

Or this whole string without the 25 gives the same result:

```
rem https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit=

Records comments (remarks) in a batch file or CONFIG.SYS.

REM [comment]
```

Comment: Putting it into doublequotes when it isn't a `rem`ark is standard practice anyhow. Try it without the `rem`, and use a URL which includes other potentially problematic characters, like `&` for instance, then doublequote the URL and see the difference.

Comment: @Compo & doesn't seem to do anything, at least in windows 10 1909

Comment: As you've clearly not embraced my previous comment in the manner I intended it, what happens when you use this specific string in the same way, _(when not a remark)_, e.g. `start https://swisscows.com/web?query=Ben & Jerry's`. Do you see an error message due to the ampersand, and do you get a browser results page for `Ben` or `Ben & Jerry's`. Now as your string is only text for reading there is absolutely no reason why you could not doublequote it, it isn't going to confuse any reader in that format, `rem "https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/bugs/4084/?limit="`.

Comment: @compo My bad, I thought you meant in an rem statement.