# windows bat file cannot comment out this

Tags: windows, batch-file, comments

I am trying to comment out some useful hints. I followed this Stack Overflow page to apply the most defensive comment - using double quotes. [Comment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491984/rem-comment-in-bat-file-causes-error-25-was-unexpected-at-this-time). But I still get error

This is my simple script: test_comment.cmd

```
@echo off

:: "   %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only "
:: "   %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only "
for /F "delims=" %i in ("c:\foo\bar baz.txt") do @echo %~nxi
```

This is the error I got when I run it

```
>test_comment
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only "


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

If I removed those two commented lines, error would disappear; so that I know the comment didn't work.

How should I comment out those two lines?

I really don't want to delete them.

I am using windows 10, latest patch, default cmd.exe.

Comment: Did you also try using `REM` instead of `::`?

Comment: yes. I used REM too, but didn't help. In my case, according to the link, :: is better than REM as REM is a command by itself.

Comment: Use `%%` in place of `%`. In a batch file, `%%` is more correct in any case, as `%~nI` is only valid at the prompt. `rem` is better that `::` because it always works, whereas `::`breaks code blocks (parenthesised sequences of lines), Unfortunately, `REM` is more intrusive visually.

Comment: [dbenham's description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/2152082) at least tells you *why* it fails (especially `Phase 1.2` and `Note 1`).

Comment: Note, that `::` is not a comment but a broken label; the `rem` command is the way to define a true comment or remark…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the link in @Stephan's comment and read: [Batch Line Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

> Phase 0) Read Line:
>
> Phase 1) Percent Expansion:
>
> Phase 2) Process special characters, tokenize, and build a cached
> command block

In short: Comment is parsed in Phase 2, after the Percent Expansion in Phase 1.

Solution: use % to escape the % in the comment, as suggested by @Magoo in the comment.

```
@echo off

:: "   %%~nI        - expands %%I to a file name only "
:: "   %%~xI        - expands %%I to a file extension only "
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("c:\foo\bar baz.txt") do @echo %%~nxI
```

Then I got the desired result

```
>test_comment
bar baz.txt
```